# Default to 100 orders in sales order admin page

Tags: adminhtml, grid, sales-order, order-grid

Could someone help me with this,

I need to change the default number orders being showed in the Admin panel/Sales/Order view page. Currently it starts from 20 per page. I want to maintain that but still by default load the page by 100 orders.

I found the code for this view in app/design/adminhtml/default/template/widget/grid.phtml

```
   <?php echo $this->__('of %s pages', $this->getCollection()->getLastPageNumber()) ?>
                        <span class="separator">|</span>
                        <?php echo $this->__('View') ?>
                        <select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>" onchange="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.loadByElement(this)">
                            <option value="20"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==20): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>20</option>
                            <option value="30"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==30): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>30</option>
                            <option value="50"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==50): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>50</option>
                            <option value="100" selected<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option>
                            <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option>
                        </select>
                        <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?><span class="separator">|</span>

  <?php echo $this->__('Total %d records found', $this->getCollection()->getSize()) ?>
```

I do not want to change the core grid.phtml. How can I do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a local.xml in /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/ (or a custom module) and add

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="setDefaultLimit">
              <limit>100</limit>
      </action> 
    </reference>
 </adminhtml_sales_order_index>

 <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="setDefaultLimit">
              <limit>100</limit>
      </action> 
    </reference>
 </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
</layout>
```

Comment: PS: remember to clear Magento Cache