# Customers per side

Tags: admin, customer, page

I recently changed the standardview for my orders to 100 per side by default as shown on this thread:

**I should mention that Magento 1 is in usage !**

[Default to 100 orders in sales order admin page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40550/default-to-100-orders-in-sales-order-admin-page)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="setDefaultLimit">
              <limit>100</limit>
      </action> 
    </reference>
 </adminhtml_sales_order_index>

 <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="setDefaultLimit">
              <limit>100</limit>
      </action> 
    </reference>
 </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
</layout>
```

Now i want to change my customers per side also to 100, is there any xml-lines i can look this through ?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try and flush cache after adding it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
 <adminhtml_customer_grid>
    <reference name="admin.customer.grid">
        <action method="setDefaultLimit">
              <limit>100</limit>
      </action> 
    </reference>
 </adminhtml_customer_grid>
</layout>
```

Comment: Didnt worked out as espected, unfortunately. The Customer list still looks like the same with 20 entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"> 
<adminhtml_customer_grid>
    <reference name="admin.customer.list">
        <action method="setDefaultLimit">
              <limit>50</limit>
      </action> 
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_grid>
</layout>
```

Thanks to @pong, just changed `admin.customer.grid` to `admin.customer.list` and flushed the chache, now it seems to be working.

Comment: this might be version issue. 19.2 + has name ""admin.customer.grid"